# sfdx:source:pull gave me the following error

Tags: salesforce

When I try to pull from a scratch org to my local I got the below error,

[image]

But when I checked the status as > sfdx force:source:status -u , Then I can see there are some remote changes like below in the image and also some unknown files like ProfileSessionSetting, ProfilePasswordPolicy. Anyone has any idea to remove it from the remote?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding following lines to .forceignore file solved the issue:

```
**/*SessionSetting*
**/*PasswordPolicy*
*SessionSetting*
*PasswordPolicy*
```

You can learn how to add .forceignore file to the project can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm)